# How to create a Postgres schema, let one role create tables in it, and let another role read from those tables

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I'm trying to set up a Postgres database using a process along the following lines:

1. A script is run, authenticated to role `postgres` that:

   - Creates a new, empty schema `schema0`.
   - Creates a role `role0` with the ability to create and populate tables in `schema0`.
   - Creates a role `role1` with the ability to retrieve data from any tables in `schema0`.
2. A migration task in AWS DMS, authenticated to `role0`, creates and populates an arbitrary number of tables in `schema0`.
3. `role1` can be used to retrieve data from any tables in `schema0`.

The tricky part is giving `role1`, in advance, the ability to read from not-yet-created tables in `schema0`. I think I should be able to do this using `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`. According to [its documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html):

> You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.

Therefore, I've attempted to accomplish my goal by making `postgres` a member of `role0` and then using `postgres` to give `user1` default privileges to tables in `schema0`, but it doesn't work.

The script for (1) includes:

```
    CREATE ROLE role0 WITH
      LOGIN
      NOSUPERUSER
      NOINHERIT
      NOCREATEDB
      NOCREATEROLE
      NOREPLICATION;
   
    CREATE ROLE role1 WITH
      LOGIN
      NOSUPERUSER
      NOINHERIT
      NOCREATEDB
      NOCREATEROLE
      NOREPLICATION;
   
   CREATE SCHEMA schema0;
   ALTER SCHEMA schema0 OWNER TO role0;
   GRANT USAGE on SCHEMA schema0 to role1;

   GRANT role0 TO postgres;
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema0 GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO role1;
```

After I execute (2), creating tables including `table0`, when I log in as `user1` and attempt to `SELECT` from `table0`, I get:

> `ERROR:  permission denied for table table0`

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is which user you use to create the tables in `schema0`. Since you say that will be `role0`, you have to add `FOR ROLE role0` to your `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement.